# Question about "subset of topological space"

Tags: general-topology

In the Topology book I'm studying, there is a exercise that starts off with the statement:

> Suppose $X$ is a topological space, $A$ is a subset of $X$...

I'm not 100% sure what this means. First of all, is a subset and a subspace the same thing in this context?

I can better express my question with an example. Let: $S$ be the set [4,8].Then let $X$ be the topological space {$S, \emptyset, [4,5) , (5,7) , (6,8], [4,7)$\ {$5$}$, (6,7), [4,8)$\ {$5$}}. Now if $A$ is a subset of $X$, which of the following could be a possible examples of $A$?

1. $A$={$S, \emptyset$}
2. $A$= [4,5)
3. $A$= (6,7)
4. $A$={$S, \emptyset,  (6,7) $}.

Which of could be $A$, and what is the difference between a subspace and a subset?

 Is my $X$ a topology on $S$?

(i'm pretty sure that 1 and 4 could be A, but 2 and 3 are in X, but they are not topologies; the question says sub**SET** and 2 and 3 are sets. )

Comment: A subset of a topological space id formally merely a subset of the *underlying* set of the topological space. I think your notation $X=\{S,\emptyset,[4,3),(5,7](6,8]\}$ is confusing. Either you did not specify what the topology of $X$ is and merely listed the underlying set of the five points of $X$ (where the points look somewhat funny). Or you meant t have $S$ as underlying set of your space $X$ and $\{S,\emptyset,[4,3),(5,7](6,8]\}$ as its topology (i.e., set of open sets); but then this fails to be a topology as it does not contain $(5,7]\cap (6,8]=(5,6], for example.

Comment: My books says a topology on a set is a collection of subsets (with the 3 properties of open sets). So I took that as basically meaning that a topological space is a collection of open balls. I came up with an obscure example for $X$ because I want to verify that my understanding is correct. So are you saying my $X$ is not a topology? I was under the impression that any collection of open balls in a set, could be a topology as long as the total set and empty set are included.

Comment: You $X$ is not a topology because the three properties of open sets do not hold. Also, a topology is not the same as a topological space (which is usually understood as the tuple consisting of the underlying set and the topology, and referred to by the underlying set alone if no confusion can arise)

Comment: I see, "..T is closed under finite intersections...[and] arbitrary unions". Thank you, You pointing that out was very helpful. I will revise my question. I also just noticed I wrote [4,3) (oops).

Comment: Usually, if $X$ is the underlying space and $\tau$ is the set of open sets, the topological space is considered to be the ordered pair $(X,\tau)$. However, sometimes the underlying space is called the "topological space" if the topology is clear from context. Here, I assume they mean that $A$ is a subset of the underlying space.

Comment: Does a subset of a topological space also have to be a topological space? Or can it be just a regular set? Or can it be a collection of sets that do not form a topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is clear that, $1$ is answer. $A$ is subset of $X$ if and only if $A‎‎\subseteq X$.

Comment: So why isn't A called a subspace? Since A is not just a set.

Comment: some subsets are subspace but not all. i suggest you read definision of subspace.  although here $1$ under operation union and intersection is a subspace.

Comment: What if A=S? Then A is in X but A is not a topology. Does this mean that, it is  not the case that, a subsets of topological spaces are also a topological space?

Comment: A subset of $X$ is loosely speaking, just  set all of whose elements are contained in $X$. Nothing to do with topology. Now, it you put a topology on $X$, a subspace will not only be a set, but will have to satisfy the topoogical requirement, which is just that the open sets are precisely the ones for which the inclusion $i:A\to X$ is continuous.

Comment: So if $A$ does not have to also be a topology, then why is my #2 above not an possible example of $A$?